# Applying CSS class conditionally in Angular2

Tags: css, angular

I have below HTML code which recursively create list items based on list returned from Component and I want to apply 'first-child' CSS class to first List item only.

```
<ul class="link-list-horz">
<li *ngFor="let menu of menulist" [ngClass]="first-child:">
 <a href="">{{menu}}</a>
</li>
</ul>

.first-child a 
{
    border-radius: 10; 
}

export class AppComponent  { 
   name = 'Quiz'; 
   menulist = ['Home','AngularQuiz'] ;  
   useremailid = 'Gaurav-Gupta'; 
}
```

Please suggest. I am totally new to Angular2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngClass` needs a condition to know whether to set that class on the element. You can use the built-in `index` that comes with `ngFor` for that.

Try this:

```
<li *ngFor="let menu of menulist; let i=index" [ngClass]="{'first-child': i === 0}">
```